# Understanding pairwise congruent modulo $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have the following small theorem in my Number Theory textbook and I need some help understanding it,

> Let $a$ and $n$ be natural numbers with $gcd(a,n)=1$ and $k=ord_n(a)$. Then the numbers $a^1,a^2,...,a^k$ are pairwise incongruent modulo $n$

Where I'm confused is the line phrase "pairwise incongruent modulo $n$". What information is this phrase telling me? What literal arithmetic is being performed in something that is "pairwise incongruent"?

Furthering this, what approach would I used to prove this theorem?

Comment: To say that some sequence $\{s_1, s_2\cdots\}$ is pairwise incongruent $\pmod n$ means that $s_i\not \equiv s_j\pmod n$ whenever $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two integers $a,b$ are incongruent mod $n$ means that $a \not\equiv_n b$. So, $a,a^2,...,a^k$ are pairwise incongruent modulo $n$ means that $a^i \not\equiv_n a^j$, for every $1\leq i <j \leq k$.

To prove the result, note that $a$ and $n$ are coprime means that there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax+ny=1$, i.e., $ax\equiv_n1$ and one can "divide by a" when working modulo $n$.

That being said, suppose that $a^i \equiv_n a^j$, for some $1\leq i <j \leq k$. Then, $1 \equiv_n a^i x^i \equiv_n a^{j-i} a^i x^i \equiv_n a^{j-i}$. But $k$ is the order of $a$ mod $n$, and that means that $k$ is the least positive integer such that $a^k \equiv_n 1$. But $0<j-i<k$, which is a contradiction with the minimality condition on $k$.

Therefore, the hypothesis that $a^i \equiv_n a^j$ for some $1\leq i <j \leq k$ is false, i.e., $a,a^2,...,a^k$ are pairwise incongruent modulo $n$.